# Why are falsy values not equal to each other in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> A falsy value is a value that translates to `false` when evaluated in a Boolean context. 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Exactly the following values are falsy in Javascript: `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`.

Now I am seeing this weird behavior: only the falsy values `false`, `0`, and `""` are equal to each other, but not equal to the other falsy values.

In addition `null` and `undefined` are not equal to any falsy values other than themselves.

And last but not least, `NaN` isn't equal to any falsy value, not even to itself!

Yet all of them evaluate to `false` in a Boolean expression like `if (value) { ... }`

What's the benefit or use case of this seemingly inconsistent behavior?

**Note:** By "equal" I mean (lax) equality defined by the `==` operator, rather than strict idendity defined by the `===` operator.

Comment: Why would you expect different types to be equal to each other?

Comment: The `==` operator has all sorts of special rules for comparisons involving some special values. [You can read all about it in the spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

Comment: Because that is how type coercion works. Tables showing all the outcomes: http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: @Blazemonger obviously because that's already the case for `false`, `0`, and `""` as the question states, for example. Hence inconsistent.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve the benefit out it here ? , undefined  .. are data types in JS , so === checks both type and value

Comment: Those are being coerced, which is what you'd expect `==` to do. The others, `null` and `undefined`, are typeless `object`s. Read their individual entries at MDN for explanations.

Comment: @Blazemonger objects are not typeless, they are of type object. And the question exactly is why the coercion is inconsistent.

Comment: Did you glean any information from MDN? [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (a special `Number`) , [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) (a primitive type and value), [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) (a primitive value). In short, the behavior is "inconsistent" because they're not all the same thing.

Comment: Frankly, I'd say it's weirder that `false`, `""`, and `0` are equal to each other. (Well, mainly that `0 == ""`; I consider it natural that `false == 0`.)

Comment: @Blazemonger for "same thing" there is identity (===) therefore this is irrelevant here. Thanks for the links but the question remains which motivation caused the definition of this behavior of lax equality (==)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why are falsy values not equal to each other in JavaScript?

Because there's a difference between two values that coerce to the same value when used as a boolean, and those two values being equal to one another.

> What's the benefit or use case of this seemingly inconsistent behavior?

There we get into largely subjective territory, which isn't really on-topic for SO. Let's just say that JavaScript's loose equality rules have long been the subject of debate and confusion. One has to remember that they were created by Brendan Eich during those mad 10 days in May 1995 in which he created JavaScript, it's no great surprise there are some "clangers" in there. And remember his task was to create a *tolerant*, forgiving language for non-programmers to program in. Hence automatic semicolon conversion, loose equality, and so on. This was a language that was meant to let you grab a value from an `input` and treat it like a number, even though the `value` of an `input` is always a string. Whether these rules achieved that goal is a matter of opinion (and I'm not advancing one here either way :-) ).

Most of the "weirdness" comes about as a by-product of rules that *mostly* seem reasonable (with, again, a couple of clangers). Let's consider the thing about `"" == 0` being true:

The rule for `==` is the [*abstract equality comparison algorithm*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), which says that if the first operand (`x`) is a string and the second operand (`y`) is a number, we return the result of `ToNumber(x) == y`. Leaving aside the question of whether a coercing equality operator is a good idea or not, if you're going to have one, that seems like a reasonable way to approach `string == number`. So we look to the [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) algorithm, which says that `ToNumber(string)` interprets the string as a number using the [ToNumber Applied to the String Type algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1), which says amongst other things that an empty string becomes `0`.

So the question isn't "why is `""` equal to `0`", it's "why does `""` coerce to the value `0` when treated as a number?" Only Eich can answer that question. :-)

There are some other fun ones in the main ToNumber algorithm, such as that `undefined` => `NaN` but `null` => `0`. Again, only Eich can explain why he thought `null` should equate to `0` but `undefined` equate to `NaN`.

It's probably worth noting that he probably didn't just pick this stuff at random. He'd studied several other languages and made choices based on that knowledge. Some of those choices may look very odd to us in retrospect ([implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)? really?), but then, most people have more than 10 days to create a language, time in which they can seek input from colleagues and the community. And again, there was that "tolerant" design criterion.

I may have strayed into some subjectiveness there. Apologies if so; I tried not to. :-)

---

Final note: If you find the rules arbitrary and hard to memorize, you aren't alone. One way to handle that is to ensure you do all your type coercion *explicitly*. But note that even if you try to do that, you're stuck with loose comparisons, because although there's a strict equality operator (`===`) and a strict inequality operator (`!==`), there are no strict versions of `>`, `<`, `>=`, or `<=`. So if you miss out an explicit coercion, your code may still seem to work if you're doing any of those other relations. I'm not advocating this (nor am I advocating against it), I've seen bugs caused both by explicit type coercion and by not having explicit type coercion. Just saying that it's one approach to the tricky rules.

Comment: @user511287 that's a question you should ask of the ECMAScript committee. It's just the way the language works, and that's the way it's been for years.

Comment: @Pointy just trying to understand the motivation behind this and how to make the best use of the language.

Comment: @user511287: IMO, avoid type coercion, unless of course you can predict what happens, e.g to Boolean conversion in `if(x)`. But the algorithm for  `==` can be hard to follow, so just avoid it,

Comment: @user511287: Well, I for one am glad that both `null` and `0` coerce to `false`, but that they aren't equal to each other. But really, the rules were determined by Brendan Eich during those mad two weeks in May 1995. It's no great surprise there are some clangers in there.

Comment: Maybe this is just not a big deal to me because I studied number theory in college, and seemingly nonsense ideas like "some infinities are larger than others" seem normal now, so to me it makes perfect sense that `NaN` wouldn't be equal to itself.

Comment: @user511287 one example: you make an AJAX call, and expect a string as an answer, eg an empty string is also valid. But you can also get an error in your call and your string variable would be undefined. You could want to get this by if (!(myStr == undefined))..

Comment: @user511287: You mention equality vs identify in one of your comments, and that makes a lot of sense. Maybe things get a bit better once we have [value types](http://www.slideshare.net/BrendanEich/value-objects).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks that makes sense, I should probably avoid to rely on an algorithm that's too weird to memorize reliably. I only wonder why they would even introduce such complex subdistinction between falsy and == in the first place if it is practically too fragile to use and remember (so to speak useless) instead of sticking with simplicity and avoid opening this box of possible bugs altogether.

Comment: @user511287: I've updated the answer a bit (well, a lot). I think the key things around some of these seemingly-weird rules are A) His task was to create a tolerate, non-programmer-friendly language. B) He had 10 days to do it. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Very thorough and thoughtful answer, that sheds some light on it.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably related to preference. `== null` is very useful to determine if something is in a "not set" state, as it also checks for undefined; but does NOT return true for values like `""`, or `0`; which will often come back from a form as valid values.

My understanding is that `NaN` fails all comparison checks so that it is noticed as soon as possible, so as to mean "This is **not** the value you were expecting." This works out if someone's type-checking block ends in an `else { throw exception because I don't know what this is! }`

Answer (score 1):

I see no benefit to comparing `false` with `0`, `""`, `null`, `NaN`, or `undefined`. There are no use cases, in my mind, that justify its use. If you write your code properly, this odd behavior is factored out. The reason the behavior exists in the first place is because JavaScript is loosely typed. Everything is an object. Best practice is to avoid use of the `==` equality operator and instead use `===`.

Fundamentally, you shouldn't allow variables to be coerced into different types across the use of a program. It hinders understandability, readability, and maintainability. It's better to code Boolean operations explicitly (i.e. do this `if (myVar === undefined) {...}`, not `if (!myVar) {...}`).

Comment: Yeah, that seems the best and solid option in face of all this mess.

Answer (score 0):

To some extent the inconsistency is probably down to "Wat?!?" - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqhZZNUyVFM.

I mean, it's kind of odd that `false`, `0`, and `""` are considered equal, given they're different kinds of thing (well, I think it's odd anyway)... but I suppose this is why JS has both a strict and a lax equality operator.

And it's why tools like jshint and jslint encourage you to only use the strict `===` operator, so you don't fall foul of this kind of weirdness. This then forces you to test for truthiness or falsiness directly, rather than via lax equality.

Or to turn it around, if you think it's odd that falsey values aren't equal to eachother, it would be weird if this *weren't* the behaviour for truthy values. For example, you'd never expect `"Bananas"` and `"Apples"` to be equal.

(And, to more directly answer your question: I'd bet some weird historical reason that might get a mention in JavaScript: The Good Parts. Beyond that I don't know.)